# Interface method - override by class

Tags: java, interface, compare

I have created an interface to be implemented by various classes all overriding the interface' methods. How do I define the compareTo() method to use various other class types?

```
public interface FootBallPlayer {
    public int playerRating();
    public int compareTo(FootBallPlayer otherPlayer);
    public String toString();
}
```

```
public class Quarterback implements FootBallPlayer {
        @Override
    public int compareTo(Quarterback otherQB) {
        
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to define an abstract `compareTo()` signature that compares each subclass to its own type? You can't really, unless you add a self-referential generic type `<T extends FootBallPlayer<T>>`, which you probably don't want. Best to just implement `Comparator` on each class individually.

Comment: compareTo() will be used inside of other classes. {Quarterback,  Runningback, etc} and  will only compare to the same type within those classes